# Optimize data lake file size: delta.targetFileSize doesn't work for 1GB file

Tags: optimization, databricks, spark-structured-streaming, filesize, delta-lake

According to this documents:
[Tune File Size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/delta/optimizations/file-mgmt#tune-file-size), I was trying to tune delta lake outputs file size to around 1gb with a streaming structure writing process. These are the codes I used:

`ALTER TABLE deltaTable SET TBLPROPERTIES (delta.autoOptimize.optimizeWrite = true, delta.autoOptimize.autoCompact = false, delta.targetFileSize = '1073741824')`

Instead of 1gb, I only get output files size around 150mb.
What could be the reason?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the linked documentation:

> If this property is set, all data layout optimization operations **will make a best-effort attempt** to generate files of the specified size

The real file size when using optimized write will heavily dependent on amount of data you're processing, number of cores, etc.

But your target file size will be taken into account when you're doing explicit OPTIMIZE.